# Honeywell android Barcode scanner

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner, honeywell

I have Dolphin 70e Black device.I want to scan QR code using the Laser Scanner in the device and How to start the scanning in the device in My App  Please help

Comment: Definitely off-topic. Use Google to get tutorials. Use official documentation to learn...

Comment: @shkschneider Google doc won't tell how to access the Dolphin barcode reader (not the camera!) input through code.

Comment: I meant the search engine...

Comment: Use Honeywell_MobilitySDK_Android available on their site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a library for scanning the barcodes from the camera.
A popular library for this is ZXing: https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Here are two nice tutorials for getting you started: 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162
http://blog.dihaw.com/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/